# JQuery .click() works in Firefox but not chrome or IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, google-chrome, click

***EDIT: Just to be clear, it's not the jsfiddle that I have a problem with. That works fine for me in all browsers, it's the actual implementation on my website which uses the exact code below.***

I have a block of 8 dynamically-generated YouTube thumbnails on a page, and a player div. When I click on one of the thumbnails, I want the associated video to ajaxly play in the player div. The following code works in FF, but not IE or Chrome.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('.vidlink').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
            alert(addressValue);

            iFrame = "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+addressValue+"\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";


            newDiv = "<div id=\"vidPlayer\">" + iFrame + "</div>";


            $('#vidPlayer').replaceWith(newDiv);

        });

});
```

[This is pretty much what I'm trying to do (JSFiddle).](http://jsfiddle.net/7veM6/13/)

It did not work in FF either, until I changed the double-quotes surrounding `$('.vidlink')` to single quotes. I tried that with the `$(this).attr("href")` but that broke it again on FF.

Comment: Any error in your console?

Comment: Wait, what's the issue? Is that JSFiddle supposed to not work in Chrome? It's working for me...

Comment: Nope, no console errors in any of the browsers.

Comment: You might have a problem in your browsers maybe you have js disabled, cause the code works everywhere.

Comment: @Jace No, sorry. The JSfiddle works in all browsers. It's only in practice on the actual website that it doesn't work in IE and FF.

Comment: @sergioadh Sorry, I might not have been clear in my question. It's not the jsfiddle that doesn't work. It's the actual code on my website that doesn't work. The jsfiddle was how I first came up with the code and illustrates what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Works in IE9 and IE10

Comment: @JasonMayoff This bug would drive me absolutely insane. Good luck!

Comment: You better give us your full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working for me in FF and Chrome and IE. The single-quotes or double-quotes shouldn't make any difference. The fact that you think it does makes me think you're not testing properly. Make sure you clear the cache in each browser. Or at least hit Refresh a couple of times before you decide whether it's working properly or not.

Comment: I've cleared the cache and refreshed several times and it doesn't work. Again, sorry if I wasn't clear in my question. It's not the jsfiddle that doesn't work, it's the actual implementation on my site.

Comment: how can you expect to get a working solution if the code you posted doesn't reproduce the problem. you need to either give people access to the page or else find a way to reproduce it. could be any number of reasons why it's not working.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that you've got some sort of race condition, which would explain why it works sometimes and not others. As a quick fix, you could try changing the '$(document).ready(' to '$(window).load('. That might fix the problem.

Comment: That worked, @Ringo. Thank you. You say as a "quick fix", is there a reason why I wouldn't want to leave it like that?

Comment: it's ok if it's working for you now. in general, if you have a lot of stuff going on on your page, it might be difficult to keep your code organized with your behaviors attached to different events. i think you should at least try to figure out why it has to wait until window.load(). it might be that the youtube data isn't getting retrieved until after you're applying the behavior. or maybe sometimes it's getting retrieved before, sometimes after. if that's the case, you can use $(document).ready() with $.on('click') instead of .click(). hey, feel free to mark my answer as correct, yeah! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

- code looks good
- the console spits out no errors
- works in JSFiddle
- quotes seem to make a difference (totally not possible, this screams to me: "you're looking in the wrong place!")

Things to check:

- It might pay to step back and look at the surrounding code
- ensure that there is no code that could possibly be unbinding your event. If there is, set up some `debugger`s/breakpoints/`console.log`s around it
- set some `debugger`s/breakpoints/`console.log`s inside your event function
- ensure your files are not being cached. If your JavaScript is in an external file, another thing I would do is navigate directly to that file and cache-refresh there.
- ensure you are viewing the correct version of your site (eg. not editing a local version, then viewing an external version)
- review all of your assumptions about what you think is happening

I'm 99% sure that the issue is not with the code you posted. I think what you've got is one of *those* errors, that when it finally works you'll be forever palming your face and losing sleep at night. We all do it!

Answer (score 0):

tries to use the Youtube API is very easy include one video, thus would you avoid errors.

A simple example can be found in https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started